# Make site mobile responsive but redirect to other site

Tags: javascript, mobile, responsive

Let's say my site is www.example.com

But when you see my site on mobile or browser inspect mode then it redirects subdomain mobile.example.com.

How can I do like this?

Thanks to inspect element, I can see it is redirect to subdomain.

Anyhelp would be appreciate.

Comment: Providing a separate mobile site is the opposite of being responsive (and is not generally recommended).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
var w = window.innerWidth;
var c = window.location.pathname;
var n = "mobile.example.com" + c;
if (w <= 768) {
    window.location.replace(n);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Is there any way that can do this on cpanel?

Comment: This is a JavaScript code. add it as the first child of the head element in your document.